# Java MYSQL, search while ignoring blank strings

Tags: java, mysql, search, jdbc, boolean

I'm trying to search on multiple tables but the user doesn't give every single input. I want to search for everything the user inputs while ignoring if the user doesn't want to search for a name for instance.
I tried the following code but it won't work unless all of the strings are provided. Is there any way to ignore that and continue the search with the information the user provided?

```
    public void BuscarCita(String aiDee, String namey, String lastNamey,String date, String horay, String miny) {
    try{
    String query=("SELECT citas.FECHA,citas.HORA,citas.MIN,citas.NOMBRE,citas.APELLIDO,citas.ID,citas.MOTIVO,user.TELEFONO,user.COMENTARIO  "
                + "from dentista.citas, dentista.user  WHERE citas.FECHA='"+date+"'"+"AND user.ID='" + aiDee+"'"+"AND citas.NOMBRE='" + namey+"'"+"AND citas.APELLIDO='" + 
                lastNamey+"'"+"AND citas.HORA='" + horay+"'"+"AND citas.MIN='" + miny+"'"+"AND citas.ID='" + aiDee+"'");
    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
    Object[] rows=null;
    while(rs.next()){
        String nomme=rs.getString("NOMBRE");
        String lnomme=rs.getString("APELLIDO");
        String datey=rs.getString("FECHA");
        String timeyH=rs.getString("HORA");
        String timeyM=rs.getString("MIN");
        String ID=rs.getString("ID");
        String reason=rs.getString("MOTIVO");
        String tel=rs.getString("TELEFONO");
        String comment=rs.getString("COMENTARIO");      
                rows=new Object[]{datey,timeyH+":"+timeyM,nomme +" "+ lnomme, tel, reason,comment};
                MainWindow.mainTableModel.addRow(rows);
    }



    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: check the answer, if that is what you want, mark the problem as solved

Answer (score 0):

you can do some thing like this:

```
String query =" Select * from table where ";
if (!name.isEmpty()){
query+= "where name='"+name+"'";}
if (!lastName.isEmpty()){
query+= "AND lastName='"+lastName+"'";
}
...
```

then you execute your query

Answer (score 0):

You can try again with my code.

```
public String trim(String input) {
    if(input == null || input.trim().length()<1) {
        return "%";
    } else {
        return input.trim();
    }
}

public void BuscarCita(String aiDee, String namey, String lastNamey,
        String date, String horay, String miny) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT citas.FECHA,citas.HORA,citas.MIN,citas.NOMBRE,citas.APELLIDO,citas.ID,citas.MOTIVO,user.TELEFONO,user.COMENTARIO "
                + "FROM dentista.citas, dentista.user "
                + "WHERE citas.FECHA= ? AND user.ID= ? AND citas.NOMBRE= ? AND citas.APELLIDO= ? AND citas.HORA= ? AND citas.MIN= ? AND citas.ID=?";
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        st.setString(1, trim(date));
        st.setString(2, trim(aiDee));
        st.setString(3, trim(namey));
        st.setString(4, trim(lastNamey));
        st.setString(5, trim(horay));
        st.setString(6, trim(miny));
        st.setString(7, trim(aiDee));

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        Object[] rows = null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String nomme = rs.getString("NOMBRE");
            String lnomme = rs.getString("APELLIDO");
            String datey = rs.getString("FECHA");
            String timeyH = rs.getString("HORA");
            String timeyM = rs.getString("MIN");
            String ID = rs.getString("ID");
            String reason = rs.getString("MOTIVO");
            String tel = rs.getString("TELEFONO");
            String comment = rs.getString("COMENTARIO");
            rows = new Object[] { datey, timeyH + ":" + timeyM,
                    nomme + " " + lnomme, tel, reason, comment };
            MainWindow.mainTableModel.addRow(rows);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```